# I am confused and I want to know the difference in both codes?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I am learning web development, and I tried to do the exercise, but the answer given is different from mine. May, anyone please help me see what my mistake is.

Here is the code:

**Given Answer:**

```js
// Setup
var contacts = [
  {
    "firstName": "Akira",
    "lastName": "Laine",
    "number": "0543236543",
    "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Harry",
    "lastName": "Potter",
    "number": "0994372684",
    "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Sherlock",
    "lastName": "Holmes",
    "number": "0487345643",
    "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Kristian",
    "lastName": "Vos",
    "number": "unknown",
    "likes": ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
  }
];


function lookUpProfile(name, prop){
  // Only change code below this line
  for (let x = 0; x < contacts.length; x++) {
    if (contacts[x].firstName === name) {
      if (contacts[x].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        return contacts[x][prop];
      } else {
        return "No such property";
      }
    }
  }
  return "No such contact";
  // Only change code above this line
}

lookUpProfile("Kristian", "lastName");
```

**My Answer:**

```js
function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {
  // Only change code below this line
  for (let i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    if (contacts[i].firstName === name && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      return contacts[i][prop];
    } else if (!contacts[i].firstName) {
      return "No such contact";
    } else {
      return "No such property.";
    }
  }
  // Only change code above this line
}
```

Calling `lookUpProfile("Kristian", "lastName")` should return the string `Vos`.

Comment: Because you always return inside the for-loop, it'll never check more than the first record (your function will work for "Akira") an nothing more. 
So, your mistake is to never allowing the loop to continue. `return` will end the loop and end the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `&&` statement has an `else` that follows it.
Therefore as soon as both statements aren't true (I.E the first example), the `else` statement that follows it will run, which `returns`, ending whatever loop the `return` is inside of.

**Your correct example , with input ("Kristian", "lastName")**

First example (Akira Laine) - Firstname is NOT Kristian, so loop continues

Second example (Harry Potter) - Firstname is NOT Kristian, so loop continues

Third example (Sherlock Holmes) - Firstname is NOT Kristian, so loop continues

Fourth Example (Kristian Vos) - FirstName IS Kristian, so loop checks if it has property
'lastname'.
It DOES have property last name, so return lastname.

**Your example, with input ("Kristian", "lastname")**

First example (Akira Laine) - Firstname is NOT Kristian, it DOES have a property 'lastname'.

Since it's a `&&` statement, it still reads as false.

Therefore, the first `else if` is checked.

First name being present IS true, so the last `else` statement is run.

This returns "no such property".

Answer (score 1):

given answer: loop all contacts, if no contact firstName match name, at last, return "No such contact".

however, you returned "No such contact" if the first contact in the loop not matching the name.